# Insert value into array object

Tags: php

I have an array which contains an number of array objects.
Is there a way to insert something in the array object for example [d] = value4 in array object [0]?

```
   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [a] => value1 
                    [b] => value2 
                    [c] => value3 )

   [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [a] => value1 
                    [b] => value2 
                    [c] => value3 )
    )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean like:

```
$thearray[0]->d = 'value4';
```

??

Comment: How do I echo say value3? I'm having a lot of greif over array objects.

Comment: @user971824: `echo $thearray[0]->c;`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$array[0]->d = 'value4';
```